# What's the difference between 運用 and 操作?

Tags: words

As i am learning Japanese,there are many words which have same meaning but still different usage,links to understand these differences would be appreciated.thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are translated to "operation" but have completely different meanings.

- 運用: "operation" as opposed to "development/test (phase)". It means actually running your system in production (and monitoring its status, replacing broken parts, etc). 稼働 is similar.

  > そのシステムは現在運用中です。
  >    The system is currently in operation.
- 操作: "operation" as a stiffer equivalent of "use". Mainly used with gadgets such as キーボード (keyboard) and スマホ (smartphone). 使用 is similar.

  > システムの操作方法を覚える
  >   to learn how to operate the system

Try to find a decent dictionary (preferably a monolingual one)!

Comment: Would 'managed larger-scale operation' vs. 'small-scale simple operation' be an appropriate way to describe the difference?

Comment: +1. Just wanted to add more information. In regular usage, 運用 is running a facility (e.g. port, airport, factory etc.) vs 操作 is operation/manipulation of a machine (e.g. crane, electrical tool, etc.).